# "Access is denied (user is not anonymous)" with spring-security-oauth2

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm new to Spring Security and Oauth, and I'm trying to set up a simple example protecting the access to resources in path "/api" with Oauth2. I'm using spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.RC2.  After some time dealing with configuration, I'm able to get tokens, but when I try to send requests to "/api" resources, I'm facing two questions:

- Initially, I'm sending authorization header with "OAuth2" prefix, but spring-security-oauth2 seems to need headers with "Bearer" prefix in the tokens to find them. What's the difference between these tokens?
- After Spring validated the token, I'm getting a security error: "ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous)" and I'm stuck with this problem. Since I'm using InMemory token store, I have to login each time to authorize client, then I'm getting this error. Here is the spring configuration:

```
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT,SCOPE_READ" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http disable-url-rewriting="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <!--intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /-->
    <form-login/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" logout-url="/logout" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="O2Server" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.o2server.security.O2ServerUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="O2Server" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="O2Client" resource-ids="O2Server" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write" secret="secret" />
</oauth:client-details-service>

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

This is the log from the server:

```
11:58:30.366 [DEBUG] FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/user/; Attributes: [ROLE_CLIENT, SCOPE_READ]
11:58:30.366 [DEBUG] FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@48a94464: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@346448: Username: paul; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails@43794494; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
11:58:30.366 [DEBUG] UnanimousBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter@4e857327, returned: 0
11:58:30.366 [DEBUG] UnanimousBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@1b4b2db7, returned: -1
11:58:30.367 [DEBUG] ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler <org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied>org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased.decide(UnanimousBased.java:90)
```

Please, could you give me some advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used oauth plugin but from reading debug output I can say that `RoleVoter` returned -1, which means access was denied by `DecisionVoter`. I see that you granted only `ROLE_USER` to principal which is trying to access url `/api/user/`, which is secured by `[ROLE_CLIENT, SCOPE_READ]` and that's the reason why access was denied.

Either grant ROLE_CLIENT and SCOPE_READ to principal or change `<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT,SCOPE_READ" />`.

Comment: Thank you Xaerxess, I guess you mean changing the rule to `access=ROLE_USER`, because now is with ROLE_CLIENT.I'm not sure, but I think that I only need a token to access an oauth resource, and the principal should get the ROLE_CLIENT, but since I'm a newbie I don't know how to achieve this, I should have missed some additional config.

Comment: Seems from code that whole magic should be in `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` - can you debug and check if `clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(username)` returns correct authorities? I think that spring forums would be better place than SP for problem like this one.

Answer (score 1):

As Xaerxess said, you should change your intercept-url access property to ROLE_USER.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_CLIENT,SCOPE_READ" />
```

to

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
```

The access property controls the **role of the user** (which the client acts on behalf of).

The documentation of the *authorities* (ROLE_CLIENT) property of tag `<oauth:client>` states:

> Authorities that are granted to the client (comma-separated). Distinct
>   from the authorities granted to the user on behalf of whom the client
>   is acting.

Also, according to user Dave Syer:

> If you didn't change Tonr, **it is not acting as a client, it is acting
>   on behalf of a user** (who will not have the required ROLE_CLIENT), so
>   it is expected that you would get a 403. If you want to make an
>   assertion about the request from tonr being from a client with a
>   specific role (without changing the app) you can use an expression,
>   e.g. "oauthClientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and hasScope('trust')".

Source: 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125468-confusing-between-ROLE_USER-ROLE_CLIENT

Comment: Thank you, with your additional comments I finally managed it, although I still have doubts between the two header types (OAuth2 or Bearer). Unfortunately, the project which I was using OAuth2 is on hold now, so I can't continue working on it for the moment