# Oauth 2 Access is denied, Scope Voter Return 0

Tags: spring, oauth

Hello I am trying to implement oAuth2 for my application, even though I implemented everything there is a problem with authentication.

This is how I try to authenticate inside security-context:

```
<http pattern="/rest/formValue/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/formValue/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

I am able to get auth token, there is no problem with that. This is how my oauth_client_detail table look like

```
{
"table": "oauth_client_details",
"rows":
[
    {
        "client_id": "client1",
        "resource_ids": null,
        "client_secret": "sahinyanlik",
        "scope": "read,write,delete",
        "authorized_grant_types": "password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit",
        "web_server_redirect_uri": "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback",
        "authorities": "ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN",
        "access_token_validity": 2147483647,
        "refresh_token_validity": 99999999,
        "additional_information": null
    }
]
}
```

I am using ROLE_ADMIN in my user_role table.

When I try to reach /formValue/1112, I am getting this error in my console;

```
13:31:51.362 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@2b595da3: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f276d6fe: Username: sahinyanlik@hotmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, , tokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
13:31:51.363 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.UnanimousBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter@4d2979be, returned: 0
13:31:51.363 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.UnanimousBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@5df7d085, returned: -1


13:31:51.371 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Previously I checked ["Access is denied (user is not anonymous)" with spring-security-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079731/access-is-denied-user-is-not-anonymous-with-spring-security-oauth2) but I couldn't figure out because when I use something like this.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/oauth/clients/.*" access="oauthClientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and oauthIsClient() and oauthHasScope('read')"  method="GET" />
```

I got error that states I can't use oauthClientHasRole"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by changing

```
<intercept-url pattern="/rest/formValue/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

to

```
<intercept-url pattern="/rest/formValue/**" access="SCOPE_READ" />
```

I found the problem by debugging.